# How to perform a root command with Pexpect?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pexpect

I'm working on a python program to assist with the apt-get tool. I want to use pexpect to download the chosen package. I believe I'm getting stuck at the child.expect line. It seems to timeout when it comes to that line.

```
butt = "vlc"
child = pexpect.spawn('sudo apt-get install ' + butt)
child.logfile = sys.stdout
child.expect('[sudo] password for user1: ')
child.sendline('mypassword')
```

This is the log file.

```
TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded.
<pexpect.spawn object at 0xb5ec558c>
version: 3.2
command: /usr/bin/sudo
args: ['/usr/bin/sudo', 'apt-get', 'install', 'vlc']
searcher: <pexpect.searcher_re object at 0xb565710c>
buffer (last 100 chars): '[sudo] password for user1: '
before (last 100 chars): '[sudo] password for user1: '
after: <class 'pexpect.TIMEOUT'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: False
pid: 27641
child_fd: 4
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
logfile: <open file '<stdout>', mode 'w' at 0xb74d8078>
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
```

UPDATE:

The password gets sent just fine. It also expects the next line as well, but then enters "Y" and does nothing.

```
child = pexpect.spawn('sudo apt-get install ' + butt)
child.logfile = sys.stdout
child.expect_exact('[sudo] password for user1: ')
child.sendline('mypass')
child.expect_exact('Do you want to continue? [Y/n] ')
child.sendline('Y')
```

SOLVED:

I needed to add this line at the end.

```
child.expect(pexpect.EOF, timeout=None)
```

Comment: FYI running `sudo apt install -y package` will auto answer yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `child.expect_exact()`.

From the docs:

> The expect() method waits for the child application to return a given string. The string you specify is a regular expression, so you can match complicated patterns.

It is good practice to use `expect()` only when the intent is to match a regular expression.

Comment: That worked. Now it expects that line and i can send the password. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 5):

The immediate problem is that this:

```
child.expect('[sudo] password for user1: ')
```

uses a regular expression. The `[...]` construct has special meaning in regular expressions, so what you're actually waiting for there is one of the letters "d", "o", "s", or "u" followed by the text `password for user1:`. But `sudo` is sending the text `[sudo]` first and the regular expression doesn't match that, because the final character of it is `]` not one of those letters.

There are numerous possible solutions to this. You can just have it match `password for user1:`. You can use `expect_exact()` as suggested by JLeClerc (which is the solution I also favor). You can escape the brackets in your regular expression so they don't have their usual meaning: `\[sudo\]` (note that when specifying this as a Python string, you will need to double the backslashes or use a raw string literal).

The other problem is that if you have already given your password in the last few minutes, you may not be prompted for it. Then the `expect()` call will definitely time out waiting for it. The easiest way to address this is to issue `sudo -k` first. You can even do it on the same command line:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('sudo -k; sudo apt-get install ' + butt)
```

Comment: I see now. When i used the line you wrote for me, it entered the command twice. What does the -k option do? Thanks.

Comment: It forces `sudo` to prompt you for your password again, instead of caching it. See `man sudo`